# Updated max input vars but table still shows error

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I recently ran into an issue with one of my DB tables were it shows error:

"Warning: A form on this page has more than 2000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration."

So I created a test.php file with:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

After loading the page in my browser I could see the `max_input_vars` was set as 1000

So I checked where the `Loaded Configuration File` was located and went in the terminal to edit it, then I had issue where it wasn't updating, and then I found out the semi-colon needed to be removed so I did that also.. still no effect... I contacted IONOS (company that owns the server) and they were useless..

Eventually, I realised I could just go into `Plesk > Tools & Settings > PHP Settings > 8.2.17 FPM application` and change the php.ini file directly in there, and after hitting "Ok" it actually updated it and applied it, so now when I go back to my test.php file I can actually see the new value, but when I refresh my table in the database it still throws the same warning message... so now I'm just completely lost and have no idea what to do..

Also, my table only has around 500 rows and 10 columns, so it's not even that big.. I'm not sure if something else is going wrong here or what..

Does anyone know if there are any other steps I can take?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your `.htaccess` file for a `php_value max_input_vars` directive?

Comment: @FiddlingAway it shows 500 error, my php configurations don't allow that unfortunately

Comment: Is the error showing up in one of your scripts, or in phpMyadmin? I'm asking because I just noticed that you said this: "when I refresh my table in the database it still throws the same warning message".

Comment: @FiddlingAway Yes, the error only shows in phpmyadmin, when I view only 25, 100, 250 rows it doesn't show the error, it only seems to show it when I set it to view all rows